# Green colored substances forming during electrolysis

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrolysis

I saw [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35381/green-color-substance-forming-during-electrolysis#comment54937_35381) but the OP didn't provide further information.

My setup is a glass container with the anode and cathode as slim metal pieces and using a 12v charger.
The solution was a saturated salt solution and tap water since I couldn't get distilled water.
My goal is to get sodium hydroxide, as explained in [here](https://www.ausetute.com.au/chloralkali.html#:%7E:text=Sodium%20hydroxide%20is%20a%20commonly,gas%20and%20aqueous%20sodium%20hydroxide.&text=Cl2(g)%20is%20produced,the%20cathode%20(negative%20electrode).), but white flakes started forming then it turned green and finally turned into orange.
The metal pieces didn't get affected they looked and felt the same didn't even get corroded oxidized.
Here is a picture of my setup; the wires of the charger are connected on top of that cap so they aren't touching the water:

[image]

Here is a picture from the internet of the material that formed; after some time that green turned into orange but not all of it

[image]

Note: while I was watching the positive side metal piece had some kind of greenish fumes coming out of its end. I found no way of filtering that green stuff out.

Comment: Please be more precise ! Explain the nature of your electrodes. In my opinion, this unwanted green stuff is produced by the electrodes which have been oxidized during the electrolysis. These electrode might be in copper, by judging the color of the insoluble stuff. Am I wrong ? And why do you use salt water ? You will never obtain sodium hydroxyde by this operation.

Comment: my electrodes are from a car space i dont know anything about it, also why i should not use salt? @Maurice

Comment: I really do not see how the following answer does not address this already: [Green color substance forming during electrolysis](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/35382/4945). The photo of your setup is also not clear enough, these nails look rusty to me. So from the information given here the most likely candidate would still be some kind of iron hydroxide.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン they dosnt address how i can filter it off thats my question at the end of it i tried filtering them using mesh and many other things but non worked

Comment: I recommend you invest some time into your question and focus it towards what you want to know. Putting it below everything, especially these oversized images, makes it easy to be overlook. Don't add it as a note. And please use proper capitalisation and punctuation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Green color substance forming during electrolysis](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35381/green-color-substance-forming-during-electrolysis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Bredget. If you don't know the nature of your electrodes, we cannot help you, because the greenish stuff is clearly coming from the electrodes, and not from the solution.
Now if you electrolyze a salt solution, you will first produce some bubbles of $\ce{H2}$ and some ions $\ce{OH-}$ at the cathode (negative pole). Simultaneously, you will produce a mixture of oxagen $\ce{O2}$ plus chlorine bubbles $\ce{Cl2}$ at the anode (positive pole). But this chlorine is rather corrosive. It will soon attack and dissolve any metal at the electrode. And it may also react with the $\ce{OH-}$ ions coming from the cathode, and produce the reaction $\ce{Cl2 + 2 OH- ->ClO^- + Cl- + H2O}$. So the solution contains more and more $\ce{ClO-}$ ions, which are powerful oxidizing agents.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, was really helpful. Do you suggest I use graphite as an anode?

Comment: Yes ! Graphite will not produce any corrosion like copper or iron. Graphite will not be chemically destroyed. But it may be victim of a physical corrosion. A graphite electrode will slowly be piulverized, with graphite powder falling down to the bottom of the solution. The best choice is platinum, which is not corroded at all.